# Python beautiful soup syntax error

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using an example I found that extracts links from an webpage

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import re

html_page = urllib2.urlopen("http://arstechnica.com")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page)
for link in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^http://")}):
print link.get('href')
```

I get:

```
File "html_test.py", line 9
    print link.get('href')
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've installed BeautifulSoup with pip to no success.

Comment: Are you by any chance using python 3.x?

Comment: Yes Python 3.5.3 on Ubuntu Linux

Comment: What python version do you use. If python 3, then `print` should be a function: `print(...)`.

Comment: In python 3, `print` is not a keyword, rather than a function. So you should do `print(link.get('href'))`.

Comment: And `urllib2` is `urllib.request`. And it's best to use `bs4` instead of `BeautifulSoup`

Comment: I may need to update Ubuntu 17.04 to 17.10, because I can't seem to even update packages....

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
```

use:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Also, in Python3, `print` is a function, not a statement:

```
print(link.get('href'))
```